# Xcode 5 : passing data between UITableViewController and UICollectionViewController without Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, uitableview, pass-data

I'm french, so sorry for my bad English...

I want to pass data `NSString *cellSelected`.
Here is my code, thanks to say what is wrong :)

```
#import "PhotoViewController.h"

@interface PhotoCategoryViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *categoryName;

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *cellSelected;

@end

@implementation PhotoCategoryViewController

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  self.cellSelected = cell.textLabel.text;

  NSLog(@"selected cell textLabel = %@",self.cellSelected);

  PhotoViewController *viewcontroller = [[PhotoViewController alloc] init];

  viewcontroller.cellSelected = self.cellSelected;

}
```

and the second class :

```
#import "PhotoCategoryViewController.h"
   @interface PhotoViewController : UICollectionViewController     <UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cellSelected;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

  NSLog(@"%@", self.cellSelected);
}
```

It's right for the first NSLog, but for the second (the passed data), that returns : "nil" ... :(

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

for the second class:

```
 @property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSString *cellSelected;
```

You need to specify it's intended to be written from the outside, with `readwrite`.
And the `copy`, to make sure the value of `NSString` is copied, and not referenced, which might get lost (This part caused me a lot of headache in the past year :) )

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying ! :)
But I've add : "@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSString *cellSelected;" in PhotoViewController.h (the second class), and that returns nil again :(

Comment: Debatable since as I said it is readwrite by default.  It certainly isn't causing the problem.

Comment: @Viny76 Since there is no segue, the ViewController is never displayed, and the `viewWillAppear` shouldn't even be called. For current debugging, try replacing `(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` with `(void)viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @thedp the same for viewDidLoad :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense, there are a couple problems here:

1. How are you presenting PhotoViewController?  Your code doesn't show it...if you are using a segue to present the view controller then you would have two instances of it.
2. Your PhotoViewController class shows an @interface definition but has a defined method in it suggesting it is an @implementation.  Are you sure you are posting the right code?
3. You should be using copy not strong references for your non-mutable properties.
4. You don't need to declare UICollectionViewController as conforming to the UICollectionViewDatasource protocol, it does this by default.

Comment: He doesn't have to segue for it to do what he wants it to do.

Comment: I know that but I don't know how he is presenting it since his code doesn't show it.  I'm just pointing out that if he IS using a segue to present it then that would explain the issue.

Comment: And the `NSLog` is in the `viewWillAppear`... Is it even being called if there is no segue?

Comment: That's why I want to know how he is presenting it.  If he is pushing or presenting his initialized instance of the PhotoViewController then this should work, but since the code isn't there I'm assuming that he might be dealing with a case where he is initializing a different instance of the view controller then what gets presented.

Comment: @smyrgl I haven't paste all my code, but he's right, no problem with interface and implementation.
I can't use segue, because I use a UIBarButtonItem with conditions in UICollectionViewController for showing another TableView. So yes, i'm pushing to my new view. :)

Comment: Then can you explain the interface problems with PhotoViewController?  It looks like an implementation file, right down to the #import of the PhotoViewController.h file.  Are you sure you are declaring the property in the public header for PhotoViewController?  You cannot use a class extension if you are setting it from an external class (well you can using KVC directly but that's not what you are doing).

Comment: @smyrgl Here is a screen from my storyboard : http://imageshack.com/a/img856/3572/nks0.png
, I would like to send data PhotoCategoryViewController to PhotoViewController (I can make it by segue I think), AND AFTER to PhotoAdminViewController (no segue, here's my problem).

Comment: @smyrgl for PhotoCategoryViewController : 
`code`
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface PhotoCategoryViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *categoryName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *cellSelected;
@end

for PhotoCategoryViewController.m : 
#import "PhotoCategoryViewController.h"
#import "PhotoViewController.h"

for photoviewcontroller.h :
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PhotoCell.h"
#import "PhotoAdminViewController.h"

for photoviewcontroller.m:

Comment: #import "PhotoViewController.h"
#import "PhotoDetailViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
#import "PhotoCategoryViewController.h"